# session not working in codeigniter some mobile phone

Tags: php, codeigniter

In mobile web application why session doesn't persist in other request i.e. session is not working in nokia featured phones i.e. Nokia Asha 503

As it's working in other phones i.e. all browsers chrome,opera,mozilla,etc.

Cookie is too enabled and codeigniter session setting is cookie instead of Database.

Answer (score 0):

use database sessions for such phones.
or use database sessions and add a cron which will keep removing old sessions or inactive sessions. 
If not please print session in consecutive request after setting session in earlier request.
As codeigniter uses cookies and database for session, you can use php session for such cases.
let me know whether php session working in requests.

Comment: yhea, I can use database sessions. but will try php sessions in such cases that's good it it's worked.